# MessageBox has 2 different styles in C++? (Windows)

Tags: c++, winapi, messagebox

Not too long ago I found that there are 2 different styles/looks for the standard Windows Message Box. The interesting thing is, even having the exact same program/code for the message box, you might get either style 1 or style 2.

[image: Message Box Style 1]
[image: Message Box Style 2]

As you can clearly see, there are some differences in the style, but the code behind them is the exact same:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

// inside DllMain
MessageBoxA(0, "MessageBoxA", "Message Box Style ...", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

I am sure you are wondering how I got two different results/styles with the same code? I made a very basic DLL which shows a message box right after being loaded/injected in a process. In most cases if you load the DLL in a console application, you will see style 1. On the other hand if you load the DLL in a GUI application (with a window), you probably will see style 2.

My question for you is why this happens, why are there 2 different styles? And is it possible to always force the message box to be in a specified style? I personally like style 2 a lot more because it looks more modern, so I would like to always have my message boxes in style 2, but how?

Comment: different versions of *comctl32.dll* -old (pre 6) and new (6+). use manifest so select new version

Comment: The solid looking text in the first dialog compared to the blurriness of the text in the second dialog can be explained by the [DPI awareness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows) of the application - which can also be set with a manifest or API call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are different commctrl versions but, as of 2022, there is no point of not using the newer style, nobody would target an older system nowadays.

Put this to a cpp:

```
#if defined _WIN64
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
```

and then you get the new styles.

Answer (score 0):

First style is compatibility with Windows 95-2000 before new XP "luna" theme. Without manifest (embedded in EXE or external file) Win32 API will use the old style. It is for compatibility with old programs which may render their own controls with the old 3D style. IMHO, the old 3D style is better. You can see when button is pushed, etc. BTW, first Windows (v1.0, 2.0) used similar to "new" flat style because most monitors were monochrome with low resolution and it was impossible to draw 3D shadows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview